# How do you create a new file in a CarrierWave process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, carrierwave

My user uploads a zip file with 3 files (A.ttf, A.svg, A.otf) and I want to store the original zip plus the 3 font files inside it.  I've created the 3 versions with this code

```
version :ttf
    process :font => :ttf
end

version :svg
    process :font => :svg
end

version :otf
    process :font => :otf
end
```

It successfully saves 4 copies of the original file, all with the proper file name.  However, I don't know how to get CarrierWave to store the individual files.  This code doesn't work.  :(

```
def font(format)
  new_file = nil

  # Loop through the zip file and extract the files
  Zip::ZipFile.open(@file.file) do |files|
    files.each do |f|
      next unless f.file?

      filename  = f.name.split("/").last
      ext       = filename.split('.').last

      # Save the file with the proper file extension
      new_file = f if ext == format
  end

  # Return the file to be stored by CarrierWave
  new_file
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, after many hours of banging my head against the wall the light finally came on.  The solution is in how CarrierWave processes the upload.  When you define a version, CW duplicates the file with a new name ([version name]_original_filename) and gives it to you in the  `current_path` variable.  You can do anything you want with this file reference (ie open the file and truncate it, or fill it with random date, etc.) and when you get done CW will store the file for you.

Somehow I missed the connection and when I realized what was going on it almost blinded me.  I'm answering this question here so that it might help some other poor soul lost in the dark.  And to show the world my ignorance.  :/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about CarrierWave. But you are returnng zip file object back. Is it what you want to pass or do you want the name of the file to be passed? Or else do you want the file to be extracted and pass the extracted file path back?

Comment: I need the extracted file to be stored.  I know my code is not quite right as far as the contents of the file, but my real problem is that CarrierWave seems to ignore whatever I return.  Even when I create a brand new file I cant get it to save my file, it just saves another copy of the original file.